# Can the access sequence of all variables in the program be analyzed through LibTooling or CFG?

Tags: clang, llvm

I want to obtain the access sequence of all variables in the program execution process through static analysis. How can I analyze the program execution flow through AST? Or use CFG to analyze to extract variable information?

Comment: Well, first of all you need to decide what you want to do, because there's a lot of leeway in what you describe, and it can easily be impossible. For example, what is the sequence in code such as `while(a.b > a.c) { switch d(a.e) case 1: f(a.b); break; case 2: g(a); break; case… }`? Is a a variable or are the individual fields variables, what about possible accesses such as in `f()` and `g()`? Once you've decided, the information in the answers to your other quesions may be enough, or not. Ask a focused question if not, please.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer, I'll put up a sample code just like this:

Comment: `struct test1{
 int a;
 int b;
};
struct test2 {
 int a;
 int b;
};

int main () {
 struct test1 t;
 struct test2 t2;
 if (t.a < t.b)
  return t.a;
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
  t.a ++;
 }
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
  t2.b ++;
 }
 return t.b;
}` I want to get the sequence like this: t.a, t.b, t.a, t.a ***,t2.b,t2.b,****  I haven't considered branching yet, but I don't know how to deal with branches like you said, and I'm not familiar with how I should learn, so I don't know where to start with this requirement

Comment: Sorry, this is too vague for me, but maybe someone else has a suggestion. Dealing with branches really is a requirement for analysing program flow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can I process branches based on AST? Still need to use CFG?

Comment: You can do many things with AST, quite possibly including what you want, when you find out precisely what you want. I suggest that you try to implement an approach, any approach. When when you can't make any further progress you may ask a *focused* question or else change your approach.